# JavaScript closure in a loop with asynchronous code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an array which contains two URLs for a web service.  The following code executes both posts correctly and prints the correct data of which to the screen.  Interestingly, however, is that the function will only print out `"2"` to the console, and yet it correctly prints out the correct number of objects in each request, screen cap:
[image]

You can see that there are a different number of objects returned from each AJAX request.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var urlList = ['../NewService.asmx/GetNames', '../NewService.asmx/GetPersons'];
            //executes both functions
            multipleAjaxCalls(urlList);
            //ajax function definition 
            function multipleAjaxCalls(array) {
                var functionArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    var func = (function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: array[i],
                            dataType: "json",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log('this is the index: ' + i);
                                console.log('ajax success ' + i);
                                console.log(data.d);
                            },
                            error: function (xhr) {
                                console.log(xhr.status);
                            }
                        })
                    })(i); //<--I honestly don't understand what passing paramters to these closing parens actually does
                           //in this case it doesn't affect the output
                    functionArray.push(func);
                }
                return functionArray //this is superfluous
            }
        });
```

Why does this function return both sets of data correctly, but only prints out the an index of `"2"`, especially when the array has a LENGTH of two?

Comment: *"I honestly don't understand what passing parameters to these closing parens actually does"* You are calling a function and passing an argument to it. Imagine you have a function `foo`. Then in `foo(i)`, you are calling `foo` and pass `i` as argument. That's what you are doing here. The only different is that you don't have a reference to the function, you are defining and calling the function "on the spot". It didn't to anything because as already noted, you didn't define the function to *expect* an argument.

Comment: @FelixKling the hero :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix

```
              function (yetanotherI) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: array[yetanotherI],
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log('this is the index: ' + yetanotherI);
                            console.log('ajax success ' + yetanotherI);
                            console.log(data.d);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr) {
                            console.log(xhr.status);
                        }
                    })
                })(i)
```

You were passing the value of i to the anony function but not using it.  I changed that.

This is how it works... the inner function does not get called before the loop has finished so when it is called `i` (the outer one) is always 2.

Comment: I haven't read it put that succintly, but that does make a lot of sense given the single-threaded nature of JS... thanks!

Comment: If the inner function does not get called before the loop finishes, why does the `url: array[i]` point to the correct index in the array..Ah!, because the index i when printed to the screen is inside the callback function in the success property.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie - that gets evaluated right away, the stuff from success only gets evaluated later.  So your way will work for the `url` parameter, but I think the code I have makes it clearer (and avoids future problems.)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this

```
(function(){
  // stuff
})(something)
```

You should be doing this

```
(function(something){
  // stuff
})(something)
```

Otherwise it won't matter if you create a closure, you're still not passing `i` to it.

Comment: wrong on two counts.  he is creating the closure that is the problem and he does not want the 2nd something, he wants the outer variable name there.

Comment: Same thing, I was generalizing the problem he had.